# Index elements of a sequence by where they would appear in a sorted copy

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, magnitude

I have a list of integers, for example:

```
my_list = [5, 2, 4, 9]
```

I want a list containing the position where each element would appear in the list if it were sorted. So in the example above, I want this result:

```
>>> sorted(my_list)
[2, 4, 5, 9]

>>> magnitude(my_list)
[2, 0, 1, 3]
```

... because after sorting:

- `5` ends up in position `2`
- `2` ends up in position `0`
- `4` ends up in position `1`
- `9` ends up in position `3`

How can I do that?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you please explain why this is the expected output for the given input?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [8]: L = [5,2,4,9]

In [9]: LL = sorted(L)

In [10]: LL
Out[10]: [2, 4, 5, 9]

In [11]: sorted(enumerate(LL), key=lambda t: L.index(t[1]))
Out[11]: [(2, 5), (0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 9)]

In [12]: [s[0] for s in sorted(enumerate(LL), key=lambda t: L.index(t[1]))]
Out[12]: [2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get half way to the solution by sorting an enumeration of the sequence – for example:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> second_item = itemgetter(1)
>>> my_list = [5, 2, 4, 9]
>>> sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=second_item)
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (0, 5), (3, 9)]
```

As you can see, each pair in the resulting list has the form `(original_position, sorted_item)` ... so that for example, `5` was originally in position `0`.

We can write a function that just returns those original positions:

```
def order(s):
    return [t[0] for t in sorted(enumerate(s), key=second_item)]
```

Let's make sure that it works:

```
>>> order(my_list)
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

The clever bit is that now we run the same function again on its own result:

```
>>> order([1, 2, 0, 3])
[2, 0, 1, 3]
```

To understand what's happening here, lets go back and see what `order()` is actually doing:

```
>>> sorted(enumerate([1, 2, 0, 3]), key=second_item)
[(2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Again, each pair has the form `(original_position, sorted_item)`, so we're effectively sorting the positions back into their original order and seeing where they end up.

All we need to do now is wrap that double use of `order()` in its own function, and we're done:

```
from operator import itemgetter

second_item = itemgetter(1)

def order(s):
    return [t[0] for t in sorted(enumerate(s), key=second_item)]

def magnitude(s):
    return order(order(s))
```

... and here it is in action:

```
>>> magnitude([5, 2, 4, 9])
[2, 0, 1, 3]
```